# Equation of a line...

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is a really embarrassing question, but could someone remind me why for any (continuous, to make this simple) function defined on $[a,b]$, the lines

$$L_1 = m(x - a) + f(a)$$

and $$L_2 = m(x - b) + f(b)$$

are equivalent? Where $m = \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b - a}$

Comment: Check that both lines go through $(a,f(a))$ and $(b,f(b))$.

Comment: I drew a picture, they do. Can I get a more analytic reason?

Comment: I don't know. What do you mean by "analytic"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to see this:

1. Since their slope is the same, they are parallel. Thus we only need to find one common point.
2. Clearly, substituting for example the point $b$, yields $L_2=f(b)$ and $L_2=f(b)-f(a)+f(a)=f(b)$

Answer (score 3):

You can verify this straightforward. We assume $m\neq 0$, then we have

\begin{align*}
m(x-a)+f(a) & = m(x-b)+f(b) \\
\Leftrightarrow x-a+\frac{1}{m}f(a) & = x-b+\frac{1}{m}f(b)\\
\Leftrightarrow b-a & =\frac{1}{m}(f(b)-f(a)) \\
\Leftrightarrow 1 & = \frac{1}{m}\underbrace{\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}}_{=m}\\
& = 1 
\end{align*}

and since $1=1$ is true, the lines are equal. Hope this helps you.

By the way I don't think your question is embarassing, I find it important remind oneself from time to time why certain things we know are true are indeed true.

Comment: $2=1$; multiply both sides by zero, get $0=0$, which is true, so the original equation is true. You can't do a proof by reasoning from what you want to conclude to something you know to be true.

Comment: well you can't if the reasoning you do is just in one direction (as in your example with the $2=1\Rightarrow 0=0$), but if you do this equivalently you can. I will add $\Leftrightarrow$ in my original post to make my reasoning clear.

Answer (score 1):

Or for the brute force approach, just put them both in $mx + b$ form:

$$L_1 = m \cdot (x - a) + f(a)$$

$$L_1 = \frac {f(b) - f(a)}{b - a} \cdot (x - a) + f(a)$$

$$L_1 = \frac {f(b) - f(a)}{b - a}x -  \frac {f(b) - f(a)}{b - a}  a + f(a)$$

$$L_1 = \frac {f(b) - f(a)}{b - a}x +  \frac {-f(b)a + f(a)a + f(a)b - f(a)a}{b - a}$$
$$L_1 = \frac {f(b) - f(a)}{b - a}x +  \frac {f(a)b-f(b)a}{b - a}$$

$$L_2 = m \cdot (x - b) + f(b)$$

$$L_2 = \frac {f(b) - f(a)}{b - a} \cdot (x - b) + f(b)$$

$$L_2 = \frac {f(b) - f(a)}{b - a}x -  \frac {f(b) - f(a)}{b - a}  b + f(b)$$

$$L_2 = \frac {f(b) - f(a)}{b - a}x +  \frac {-f(b)b + f(a)b + f(b)b - f(b)a}{b - a}$$

$$L_2 = \frac {f(b) - f(a)}{b - a}x +  \frac {f(a)b - f(b)a}{b - a}$$

$$L_1 = L_2$$

For the less brute force approach, a function $y = f(x - k) + j$ is the function $f$ shift right by $k$ and up by $j$ (this is very important for understanding functions).

Your function is $y = mx$.

So in case $L_1$ we shifted right by $a$ and up by $f(a)$.  In case $L_2$ we shifted right by $b$ and up by $f(b)$.

$L_2$ is $(b - a)$ more to the right than $L_1$.  $L_2$ is $f(b) - f(a)$ more up than $L_1$.  But that ratio is your slope, so you have the same line.